# Is there a way to return boolean success of BST removal in one traversal?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

That is, return a boolean of whether or not an element was actually removed in the tree.

The common implementation is to call find() to see if the element is in your tree and return false if find() fails to find the target. This requires going down the tree twice: once for find() and once for remove().

One way is to set a private field flag that you will set upon finding the element during remove(). Seems kinda gross though. Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: Why would you have to search twice? Find it, if it's there remove it and return true, otherwise return false.

Comment: BST removals are recursive. How can you return true while also returning a Node (to set the root of the new subtree)?

Comment: Implementation details. Are you talking about specific code? Perhaps you should post it.

Comment: @user3724404: By using (or simulating) a language in which it is possible to return two things (or a tuple of two things). Or by returning Maybe(newroot), where the newroot is only returned if the deletion happened. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the elements in the BST in one traversal itself. There is no need of seperate traversal for finding the element in the removal process. To do remove the elements in the BST in one first traversal follow the steps:

1. Search for the node to be deleted.
2. If the node is found apply the removing algorithm

To clear understanding refer[enter link description here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/)

Comment: Perhaps you are misunderstanding the question? You have no way of knowing, by calling that void function, whether or not an element was removed from your tree.